# Remove pop-up window when running an operator

Tags: shortcut, operator, windows

Is there anyway to remove this pop-up window when running an operator?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it is possible for add-ons if you change their respective scripts, may I ask why this panel bothers you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewport menu just **uncheck** the option ***View → Adjust Last Operation*** and the popup no longer appears. You still can hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring it back and adjust the last operation.